# References on history of topology and categorical aspects of topology.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

I am currently writing the conclusions of my bachelor's thesis on convergence spaces and there are a couple of points I would like to make, but lack the proper references to cite in order to do so.

The first point I would like to make is that one of the starting points of General Topology was trying to axiomatize the notion of convergent sequences and hence the notion of a convergence space is much closer to the origins of topology. I recall reading somewhere that the first attempts of defining topological spaces were like that, but I can't find where.

The second point is that the category of convergence spaces is much more adequate than Top, because it has exponential objects. I know there is a whole discussion of the importance of having cartesian closed categories of spaces, but I by myself cannot argument that, because my background on category theory is really small. Therefore, I need to cite someone who knows that for a fact and can give reasons why that is.

Hopefully I am not breaking any rules by asking two different sources in the same post. I thank gratefully for any answer.

Comment: Hyland in [Filter spaces and continuous functionals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484379900068) discusses what he calls *L-spaces* (see p.124). These objects are also called *limit spaces*. Hyland states that L-spaces were previously introduced by Kuratowski under the name *L$^*$-spaces*. I don't know the history of L$^*$-spaces, but if you can trace it back, I wouldn't be surprised to see that they were originally one of the earlier attempts to axiomatize convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introduction to the paper *The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points
in analysis and topology* by Gregory H. Moore could be worked into your first point.

For the second, see the paper *An Initiation into Convergence Theory* by Szymon Dolecki (in the collection *Beyond Topology*) or the book *Convergence foundations of topology* by Dolecki and Mynard. This [thesis](https://surface.syr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1152&context=etd) also makes similar points. If you want a different source, try Chapter 4: Cartesian Closed Topological Categories of Gerhard Preuss' *Theory of topological structures: an approach to categorical topology.*

Comment: Thanks for the first one! The second one actually I have cited so much already in my text that I believe it's too much haha, so I'll keep on looking (Lawvere has many comments in this regard in case anyone is interested, as far as I've seen).

Comment: I've added an alternative

Comment: Maybe also include the chapters by Thron (*Frederic Riesz’ Contributions to the Foundations of General Topology*) and Herrlich/Strecker (*Categorical Topology − Its Origins, as Exemplified by the Unfolding of the Theory of Topological Reflections and Coreflections before 1971*) and Frič (*History of Sequential Convergence Spaces*) in [**Handbook of the History of General Topology**, Volume 1](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-0468-7) by Aull/Lowen (1997). @Bryan Castro

Comment: Thanks to both of you!